# Run python script in VB.net on button click

Tags: python, vb.net, cmd

I want to run a Python script in cmd when a button is clicked in VB.Net.
Do you need to call the Python script in a batch file? Or can you do it directly in VB?

I tried this

```
Dim ps As New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    ps.Arguments = "C:\yourbatfile.bat"
    Process.Start(ps)
```

But that only opens the cmd window and doesn't execute the bat file.

Comment: I think the argument you sent is incorrect (usually you'd suffix it with `/c` or `/k` when running cmd), but why open cmd when you can just execute the batch file immediately? `Process.Start("C:\yourbatfile.bat")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim psi = New ProcessStartInfo("c:\python27\python.exe", "myPythonScript.py")
Dim proc = Process.Start(psi)
proc.WaitForExit()
If proc.ExitCode <> 0 then throw new Exception(" Script Failed")
```

Comment: I get this error with that code:  'System.Diagnostics.Assert' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Friend'.

Comment: That was just to show you how to test the exit code to see if errors had occurred. I've changed it to throw an exception now.