# Can you run a python file using visual basic

Tags: python

As a little project I would like to make a movie suggester program
I will use a web crawler to get a list of movies from imdb. I've made a web crawler out of python however i hate guis on python and so I will use VB. I have only been coding for 2 years and I'm only 15 years old so I won't understand any super complex comments. Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825514/run-python-script-in-vb-net-on-button-click ?

Comment: i don't know VB, but what i can suggest is using python store data in csv or json file. and the from this read the data and use it in visual basic. how to connect visual basic code with python code as example given by ramy , you can use bat file to run python task (basically write all command to scrap data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use VB Process.Start(...)

```
Dim pythonProcess As New Process()
With pythonProcess
    .StartInfo.FileName = "python"
    .StartInfo.Arguments = yourScriptFileName
    .Start()
End With
```