# Python run a VB.net button

Tags: python, vb.net

Following is my `.py`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call('Project1.exe',shell=True,cwd='./')
```

I run a VB.net form by python,

But I want to know how to click button on vb.net form using Python?

Any idea?

I find a opposite question in here

[Run python script in VB.net on button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825514/run-python-script-in-vb-net-on-button-click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use `pywinauto` to do the job,

Here's the code

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
app = Application('uia').start('Project1.exe')
app['Form2'].GWLF_GOButton.click_input()
```

so simple code to do it